# How can I implement this loader for my project?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Basically, I am trying to implement a loader for my clock project. However, for some reason, it does not work. I have tried moving my code around to see what's wrong, but I have not figured it out. However, if I remove the div that my clock is in, the loader appears and fades out which is what I want it to do. How can I produce my loader so it appears, fades out, and shows the clock? Any help is appreciated. Here is my code below.

```js
setInterval(setClock, 1000)

const hourHand = document.querySelector('[data-hour-hand]')
const minuteHand = document.querySelector('[data-minute-hand]')
const secondHand = document.querySelector('[data-second-hand]')

function setClock() {
    const currentDate = new Date()
    const secondsRatio = currentDate.getSeconds() / 60
    const minutesRatio = (secondsRatio + currentDate.getMinutes()) / 60
    const hoursRatio = (minutesRatio + currentDate.getHours()) / 12
    setRotation(secondHand, secondsRatio)
    setRotation(minuteHand, minutesRatio)
    setRotation(hourHand, hoursRatio)
}

function setRotation(element, rotationRatio){
    element.style.setProperty('--rotation', rotationRatio * 360)
}

setClock()
```

```css
.loader-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #292929;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loader-circles{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.loader-circles .circle{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;

}

.loader-circles .circle:nth-child(even){
  border-color: #42CAFD;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.loader-circles .circle:nth-child(odd){
  border-color: #EFD2CB;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.loader-circles .circle:nth-child(1){
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(2) {
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 6s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(3) {
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 4s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(4) {
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 3s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(5) {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 2.4s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(6) {
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 2s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(7) {
     width: 140px;
     height: 140px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 1.7142857143s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(8) {
     width: 160px;
     height: 160px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(9) {
     width: 180px;
     height: 180px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 1.3333333333s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(10) {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 1.2s;
}

 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.clock {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.clock .number{
    --rotation: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.clock .number1 { --rotation: 30deg;}
.clock .number2 { --rotation: 60deg;}
.clock .number3 { --rotation: 90deg;}
.clock .number4 { --rotation: 120deg;}
.clock .number5 { --rotation: 150deg;}
.clock .number6 { --rotation: 180deg;}
.clock .number7 { --rotation: 210deg;}
.clock .number8 { --rotation: 240deg;}
.clock .number9 { --rotation: 270deg;}
.clock .number10 { --rotation: 300deg;}
.clock .number11 { --rotation: 330deg;}

.clock .hand{
    --rotation: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    z-index: 10;
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
}

.clock::after{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 11;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.clock .hand.second{
    width: 3px;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: red;
}

.clock .hand.minute{
    width: 7px;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: black;
}

.clock .hand.hour{
    width: 10px;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: black;
}
body {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.section {
    min-height: 820px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif, arial;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, p {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif, arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.title-top {
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.title-bottom {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.title-tx {
    font-size: 20px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
/* Navbar */

.nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 9;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.nav a {
    padding: 7px 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    border-style: ridge;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif, arial;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.nav a.active {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
}
.nav a:hover {
    background: rgba(250, 164, 84, 0.795);
    color: white;
}
/* Sections */

#section1{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5799 0%, #2ce0bf 20%,       #76dd2c 40%, #dba62b 60%, #e02cbf 80%, #1e5799 100%);
    background-size: 10000px 100%;
    animation: bg 15s linear infinite;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
    
}

@keyframes bg {
     0% {
         background-position-x: 0;
    }
     100% {
         background-position-x: 10000px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Animations Page HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--Links and Fonts-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JavaScript Clock</title>
     <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Audiowide&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="loader-wrap">
    <div class="loader-circles">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <div class="nav">
        <nav>
            <a class="active" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
  <!--Lesson 1-->
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class = "clock">
       <div class = "hand hour" data-hour-hand></div>
       <div class = "hand minute" data-minute-hand></div>
       <div class = "hand second" data-second-hand></div>
       <div class="number number1">1</div>
       <div class="number number2">2</div>
       <div class="number number3">3</div>
       <div class="number number4">4</div>
       <div class="number number5">5</div>
       <div class="number number6">6</div>
       <div class="number number7">7</div>
       <div class="number number8">8</div>
       <div class="number number9">9</div>
       <div class="number number10">10</div>
       <div class="number number11">11</div>
       <div class="number number12">12</div>
   </div>  
    </div>
  <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.loader-wrap').fadeToggle();
    }, 2500);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add Z-index to the parent container of either the Clock or the loader:

Here I add a z-index on the container of the clock:

```
#section1{
  z-index: -1;
}
```

So the loader and your clock are overlapping on one another and the clock has higher priority in terms of your HTML which is below the loader HTML-markup and that is why the clock shows on top of the Loader.

```js
setInterval(setClock, 1000)

const hourHand = document.querySelector('[data-hour-hand]')
const minuteHand = document.querySelector('[data-minute-hand]')
const secondHand = document.querySelector('[data-second-hand]')

function setClock() {
    const currentDate = new Date()
    const secondsRatio = currentDate.getSeconds() / 60
    const minutesRatio = (secondsRatio + currentDate.getMinutes()) / 60
    const hoursRatio = (minutesRatio + currentDate.getHours()) / 12
    setRotation(secondHand, secondsRatio)
    setRotation(minuteHand, minutesRatio)
    setRotation(hourHand, hoursRatio)
}

function setRotation(element, rotationRatio){
    element.style.setProperty('--rotation', rotationRatio * 360)
}

setClock()
```

```css
.loader-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #292929;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.loader-circles{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.loader-circles .circle{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;

}

.loader-circles .circle:nth-child(even){
  border-color: #42CAFD;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.loader-circles .circle:nth-child(odd){
  border-color: #EFD2CB;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: transparent;
}

.loader-circles .circle:nth-child(1){
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(2) {
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 6s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(3) {
     width: 60px;
     height: 60px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 4s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(4) {
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 3s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(5) {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 2.4s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(6) {
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 2s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(7) {
     width: 140px;
     height: 140px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 1.7142857143s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(8) {
     width: 160px;
     height: 160px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(9) {
     width: 180px;
     height: 180px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 1.3333333333s;
}
 .loader-circles .circle:nth-child(10) {
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     animation: rotate-circle linear infinite;
     animation-duration: 1.2s;
}

 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
 @keyframes rotate-circle {
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.clock {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.clock .number{
    --rotation: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transform: rotate(var(--rotation));
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.clock .number1 { --rotation: 30deg;}
.clock .number2 { --rotation: 60deg;}
.clock .number3 { --rotation: 90deg;}
.clock .number4 { --rotation: 120deg;}
.clock .number5 { --rotation: 150deg;}
.clock .number6 { --rotation: 180deg;}
.clock .number7 { --rotation: 210deg;}
.clock .number8 { --rotation: 240deg;}
.clock .number9 { --rotation: 270deg;}
.clock .number10 { --rotation: 300deg;}
.clock .number11 { --rotation: 330deg;}

.clock .hand{
    --rotation: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    z-index: 10;
    transform: translate(-50%) rotate(calc(var(--rotation) * 1deg));
}

.clock::after{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 11;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.clock .hand.second{
    width: 3px;
    height: 45%;
    background-color: red;
}

.clock .hand.minute{
    width: 7px;
    height: 40%;
    background-color: black;
}

.clock .hand.hour{
    width: 10px;
    height: 35%;
    background-color: black;
}
body {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.section {
    min-height: 820px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif, arial;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, p {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif, arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.title-top {
    font-size: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.title-bottom {
    font-size: 30px;
}
.title-tx {
    font-size: 20px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
/* Navbar */

.nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 20px;
    z-index: 9;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.nav a {
    padding: 7px 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    border-style: ridge;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif, arial;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.nav a.active {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    color: white;
}
.nav a:hover {
    background: rgba(250, 164, 84, 0.795);
    color: white;
}
/* Sections */

#section1{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5799 0%, #2ce0bf 20%,       #76dd2c 40%, #dba62b 60%, #e02cbf 80%, #1e5799 100%);
    background-size: 10000px 100%;
    animation: bg 15s linear infinite;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Audiowide', cursive;
     z-index: -1; /* ADDED THIS LINE OF CSS */
    
}

@keyframes bg {
     0% {
         background-position-x: 0;
    }
     100% {
         background-position-x: 10000px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Animations Page HTML-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!--Links and Fonts-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JavaScript Clock</title>
     <script defer src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Audiowide&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="loader-wrap">
      <div class="loader-circles">
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="circle"></div>
          <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
    <!--Navbar-->
  <div class="nav">
      <nav>
          <a class="active" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
      </nav>
  </div>
  <!--Lesson 1-->
  <div class="section" id="section1">
   <div class = "clock">
     <div class = "hand hour" data-hour-hand></div>
     <div class = "hand minute" data-minute-hand></div>
     <div class = "hand second" data-second-hand></div>
     <div class="number number1">1</div>
     <div class="number number2">2</div>
     <div class="number number3">3</div>
     <div class="number number4">4</div>
     <div class="number number5">5</div>
     <div class="number number6">6</div>
     <div class="number number7">7</div>
     <div class="number number8">8</div>
     <div class="number number9">9</div>
     <div class="number number10">10</div>
     <div class="number number11">11</div>
     <div class="number number12">12</div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.loader-wrap').fadeToggle();
    }, 2500);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, would I do have to add a z-index for the "Section 1" to appear after the loading screen as well?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by that, are you telling me that the ` <a class="active" href="#section1">Section 1</a>` once click, will show the clock? It's not actually possible for an anchor-element to do this. As I said before, the clock and the loader are overlapping to one another. So clicking the <a> will only put the element on the top of the screen, but since its overlapping, its already on the top of the screen.  If you want to click a button and then show the clock. You can create a button and run a specific function such as this [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)